# sharedpreferences between activities

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, savestate

This question is kind of similar to other sharedpreferences questions but i don't really know how exactly to use it between different activities? Kindly provide the complete activity file if possible rather than just few lines of codes as i am noob in this field!

I have two activities. one is userprofile and another is edituserprofile. Whatever a user edits in edituserprofile, should be displayed in userprofile activity as soon as user click on save image button from the app bar of edituserprofile. sharedpreferences works perfectly in edituserprofile where user can see entered data and also able to change it as it is edittextview. However, i am not able to apply the same logic to userprofile activity. When i click on save button from edituserprofile, it takes me to userprofile and i can see the change that has made in edituserprofile but as soon as i exit the userprofile and relaunch it, data gets cleared in userprofile but not from edituserprofile! i want userprofile to save, display data from edituserprofile even user exit and re-launch the app!

Below is userprofile activity!

```
package com.example.android.coffeeshop6menus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int Edit_Profile = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        Toolbar userProfileToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(userProfileToolbar);
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        displayMessage(sharedpreferences.getString("nameKey", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.userprofile_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_editProfile:
                Intent userProfileIntent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, EditUserProfile.class);
                startActivityForResult(userProfileIntent, Edit_Profile);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Edit_Profile:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String name = data.getStringExtra("");
                    displayMessage(name);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.importProfile);
        usernameTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Below is edituserprofile activity that works perfect!

```
package com.example.android.coffeeshop6menus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditUserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user_profile);
        Toolbar userProfileToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(userProfileToolbar);
        TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            usernameTextView.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .coordinatorLayout);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.editprofile_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save:
                TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
                String usernameString = usernameTextView.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Name, usernameString);
                editor.apply();
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                snackbar.show();
                Intent userProfileIntent = new Intent(EditUserProfile.this, UserProfile.class);
                userProfileIntent.putExtra("", usernameString);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, userProfileIntent);
                finish();

        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Below is the userprofile.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.coffeeshop6menus.UserProfile">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/importProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="@string/userNameImport"
            android:textSize="20dp" />





    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Below is the edituserprofile xml file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.coffeeshop6menus.UserProfile">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="User Profile"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:hint="@string/EditTextHint"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usercontact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:hint="@string/usercontactHint"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/useremail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:hint="@string/useremailHint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UserProfile` class and everywhere else change -

> SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

by this -

```
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("nameKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And you are good to go !

Comment: Tysm! it worked! i just needed to do it in UserProfile class as sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Name, MODE_PRIVATE);
        displayMessage(sharedpreferences.getString("nameKey", ""));

Answer (score 1):

You are using sharedpreferences which are local to your two activities, as in [docs for this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)):

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity.

Solution is to use global sharedpreferences with:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

A major dilemma is that you are using `getPreferences()` in UserProfile, but using `getSharedPreferences()` in EditUserProfile. The first method would only get key-value pairs for the UserProfile activity, while the second is for any part of the app to access. Switch `getPreferences()` to `getSharedPreferences()` and you should be good.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

From that website:
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: that means if we want to use sharedpreferences within activity, we have to use getPreferences() and if we want to use it between activities, we have to use getSharedPreferences()...is it so? btw, tysm for the help! it worked!

Comment: It's not so much that you have to use the first one for just a single activity, but that it's more helpful. Those key-value pairs will only be available to that activity. `getSharedPreferences()` creates pairs that are available for the whole app.

Comment: Sorry, another important note, `getSharedPreferences()` creates multiple preference "files", which is that first string you specify in calling that method. `getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);`

Comment: im sorry but i could not get it! can you explain it with little example? sorry to bother you!

Comment: Sure. The android website says that `getSharedPreferences()` is for "if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter." This means that, say you want two people to be able to login. That means two usernames and two of anything else associated with those things. Instead of saying something like `editor.putString(Name1, usernameString);` and `editor.putString(Name2, usernameString);`, you could just open two shared preference FILES. 
`getSharedPreferences("First User", 0);` and `getSharedPreferences("Second User", 0);`.

Comment: That way you could just use the same constant strings you've been using in your code, but with a different file. `editor.putString(Name1, usernameString)`

Comment: same constant strings and it will retrieve applicable one? means, it will see which one is edited and should be open? sorry, for asking too many questions!

Comment: http://skillgun.com/question/465/android/basics/what-is-the-difference-between-getpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences-in-android-to-secure-preference-file-from-other-activities-in-an-android-application-which-one-to-use-getpreferences-or-getsharedpreferences

Comment: Means that, yeah, you use the same constant strings, but which editor is open will determine what data you get